# Building link to post in facebook business manager

Tags: php, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, integration

We are building an app that creates campaigns and publishes these on our users facebook pages trough our business manager account. We have one part here where we want our users to be able to view their post on business manager. Mailchip does this for example using the following link format:

https://business.facebook.com/{page-id}/posts/{some-id}

The problem we have though is that we can't find the last ID to place in the URL. None of the ones we've found from the API works (campaign_id, ad_id, ad_set_id, ad_creative_id, object_story_id etc).

It is possible to get to this link from inside the business manager if we go trough the notifications and click on a notification related to the post. It perhaps would be possible to go this way but we also can't find anything related to this in the documentation.

Anyone knows how to retrieve this ID?